# Error in enum init

Tags: java, error-handling, static, enums, init

I have a question, what happens if an error happens during of creation of enum constant?
I.e. i have an enum

```
 Enum statuses{
 OPEN(1, init(1)), CLOSE(2, init(2));
 private final int value;
 private final int internalValue;

 statuses(int v, int intv){
 this.value = v;
 this.internalValue = intv;
 }

  static int init(int value){
 return get a value from db and return it;

 }
 }
```

Now what happens if there is an error in init method i.e. connection lost , will enum type will be initialized or what? Should I handle possible errors in init method and return default value and then check for it re init enum constant?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Answer (score 3):

> Now what happens if there is an error in init method i.e. connection lost , will enum type will be initialized or what?

You'll get an [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) and your program will (almost certainly) terminate.

This is trivially answerable with a simple test:

```
class Main
{
     enum Statuses{
         OPEN(1, init(1)), CLOSE(2, init(2));

         private final int value;
         private final int internalValue;

         private Statuses(int v, int intv){
             this.value = v;
             this.internalValue = intv;
         }

         static int init(int value){
            if (value == 2) throw new RuntimeException("this is a test");
            return value;
         }
     }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
                System.out.println(Statuses.OPEN);
        }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: this is a test
    at Main$Statuses.init(Main.java:18)
    at Main$Statuses.<clinit>(Main.java:7)
    ... 1 more
```

http://ideone.com/YQ8FTB

Comment: Thank you, what do u suggest to handle such a situation?

Comment: @user2355990 there is no universal answer. It depends on the variety and recoverability of the failure modes. If it's a critical, nonrecoverable error, then your app should crash.

Answer (score 2):

Java `enum` is just a class with some automatically generated code. All enum entries are `public final static` fields that are initiated when class is loaded. If exception is thrown during initalization you will not be able to use enum: every attempt to access it will throw exception.

BTW IMHO using code that is supposed to throw exception into enum initialization is a bad practice. You should either write enum hard-coded or make this initialization lazy or transform enum to ordinary class.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to use something like cache for my app, enum is not a good choise? I wanted to associate a value from db, which may change from time to time, with an enum constant, and use it in web app, but if it may fall during initialization, i have no way to re init it?

Comment: You can add a getter to your enum which retrieve the value from database when first needed, and cache the result for future access (aka lazy initialization)